# jquery .animate callback executing automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

```
$(function(){
$("#obj").click(function(){
    $("#theimage").animate({height: '334px', width: '500px'},function(){
        $("#obj").click(function(){
        $("#theimage").animate({height: '150px', width: '250px' })
        });
    });
});
});
```

the first animate makes the image 500x334 and the callback is supposed to execute once you click the image again which will make it small, however the callback is executing automatically (i think this is supposed to happen) but I was wondering if there was a way to stop it from executing and then when you click the image it will then animate again? When i added a .stop it worked once and then after that it kept executing twice?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are registering a click handler within another one, so when the second click happens your first and second will get triggered

```
$(function () {
    var flag = false;
    $("#obj").click(function () {
        if (flag) {
            $("#theimage").stop(true, true).animate({
                height: '150px',
                width: '250px'
            })
        } else {
            $("#theimage").stop(true, true).animate({
                height: '334px',
                width: '500px'
            });
        }
        flag = !flag;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `callbacks` are made for executing a set of code after an `animation or a particular job` completed. So whenever the first `animation` got executed completely, obviously the call back part should get executed. Try like this,

```
$(function(){

$("#obj").click(function(){

    if (parseInt($("#theimage").width()) === 500)
       {
          $("#theimage").stop().animate({height: '150px', width: '250px' })
       }
   else
       {
          $("#theimage").stop().animate({height: '334px', width: '500px'});
       }
 });

});
```

### [LIVE - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmw9T/)